# matplotlib get errorbar color from legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Is there anything equvilent to this code

```
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3],label='22')
z  = plt.legend()
tm = z.get_lines()
tm[0].get_color()
```

but for errorbars?

```
plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0.5,0.5,0.5],label='22')
z  = plt.legend()
tm = z.get_ ???? 
tm[0].get_color()
```

I did z.get+ 
This is what I see:
[image]

I tried many of them but no luck

Thank You.

Comment: Look at what is in `z.legendHandles`

Comment: In many programmer editors and in the `ipython` interactive interpreter you can write z.get_<TAB> to have a list of the possible methods.  In many cases you can also complete and ask for the method signature and/or the help string, but the details vary much more.

Comment: And if you can't use tab, try printing out `dir(X)`, that will give you all of it's methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Added proper solution thanks to people from the mailing list.

### Workaround way

My best solution so far has been something like this:

```
plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0.5,0.5,0.5])
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None) # Reset the color cycle to get the same one
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3],label='22')
z = plt.legend()
tm = z.get_lines()
tm[0].get_color()
```

That is plotting the data again. Of course you don’t get the same markers in the legend; in my case this wasn’t an issue (I’m replacing them by coloring the labels) but YMMV.

### Proper way

Scott Lasley hinted that the way to do this is to manipulate `plt.legend().legendHandles` as pointed by Tom Caswell in answer to OP. They are two subtleties though, the first one is that we are handling `LineCollection` and not `Line2D` as noted by Paul Hobson (so that we get arrays in returns), the second is that colors are returned as RGBA arrays instead of HEX values, which might be of importance depending on your use case. So, to get the exact same outputs as in the `plt.plot()` case with `plt.errorbar()`, you need to do as follow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0.5,0.5,0.5])
z = plt.legend()
tm = z.legendHandles
to_hex(tm[0].get_colors()[0]) # tm[0].get_colors() looks like [[r g b a]]
```

If you don’t care about the color format, you can remove `to_hex` import and use.